# Move Woocommerce Product Image Gallery to Side of Featured Image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I'm customizing a WordPress theme with WooCommerce installed. The client would like the image gallery on the single product page moved from beneath the main image to beside it (under the product summary). I tried simply moving `do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );` from `product-image.php` to after the summary in `content-single-product.php`, but that broke the ability to change the featured image to what you've clicked and also broke the lightbox functionality.

What do I need to do to get that gallery over to the right side where I want it?

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the action and then add it back in to re position the product photos underneath the product summary.  Add this code to your functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 25 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 25 );
```

The only thing with this is that how it looks is dependent on what theme you are using the gallery won't be 100% width of the column.  I tried it with the 2016 theme and used this CSS to make the gallery full width of the page.

```
#content .twentysixteen div.product div.images {
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did know about this method, and it does move the images where I want. However, it seems to break the lightbox and featured image update functionality.

Comment: Lightbox works fine for me on the 2016 theme.  You'll have to elaborate on what you mean by breaks it?  Are there any errors in the console? What theme are you using?

Comment: In that case, it may be an error in my theme. I&#39;m using a child theme of Understrap (I know, not the best, but it&#39;s what it is). I'm not getting any console errors, so I'll have to do some testing I guess.

Comment: @KreigD I use them all the time they are fine, maybe update to the latest version of the child theme it might have enhanced WooCommerce support.  Failing that do you need the lightbox functionality? If not then switch it off with some actions.

Comment: I do need the lightbox functionality. I'm sure it's just something in the child theme screwing it up, I'll just have to find it.

Comment: @KreigD any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, no errors

Comment: Hmm can't chat with you your rep is too low lol.  Have you read this article ? https://createandcode.com/broken-photo-gallery-and-lightbox-after-woocommerce-3-0-upgrade/

Comment: Yeah I've read that, and it didn't change anything for me.